# Singleton - Compactness by Subcover Definition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that the singleton is compact by the Heine Borel Theorem. However, how can I prove that it is compact using the definition?

I am defining compactness of the set A by if A is compact then every open cover of A have a finite subcover.

On a related note, how can I get better at proving compactness by the definition?

I am considering the usual Rn topology.

Thank you

Comment: choose one set of any open cover containing the singleton, and that's a finite subcover

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a singleton $\{x\}$, then any cover of $X$ must contain the open set $\{x\}$ ($\{x\}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but it is relatively open in $X$), so you have a subcover with only one open set, $\{x\}$.

In general, if $X$ is finite, $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, then if you are given an open cover, you can pick elements of the cover $A_1,\dots,A_n$ such that $x_i\in A_i$, and then $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$ is a finite subcover of $X$.

In general proving compactness by definition is not the most common method, except in some easy cases like finite topological spaces or spaces with the trivial or finite complement topology.

In most cases, you prove compactness using the properties of compact spaces, like:

Product of compact spaces is compact.

Continuous images of compact spaces are compact.

Closed subspaces of compact spaces are compact.

Finite union of compact subspaces is compact.

If your space is T$_2$, arbitrary intersections of compact subspaces are compact.

Or characterizations of compactness, like the Heine Borel theorem.

Comment: By definition only is not very common for *concrete examples*, agreed, except for the easy cases you mentioned. But the defintion *is* used  a lot to prove the theorems you state, so for that reason alone it should be every familiar. The OP will encounter these proofs later, or so we hope.